# python doesnt find module, although installed via conda

Tags: python, module

Python doesnt find 'xarray', although I installed it via conda.
How to solve this?

Comment: Please replace the images with formatted code/text in the question. See also: [ask] and [How to format code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you installed `xarray` in the base conda environment, but you're calling python in the mlenv environment. You need to switch the active environment from base to the one you're using before attempting to install `xarray` with conda.

In linux:

```
source activate mlenv
conda install xarray
```

In windows:

```
activate mlenv
conda install xarray
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for xarray but for the next module 'cmocean', I get a ModuleNotFoundError, although it says that "All requested packages are already installed."

Comment: I think that's a module within matplotlib, so maybe `conda install matplotlib` after activating the environment. Might be better to post a new question with the details there.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Since my question was downvoted stackoverflow doesnt allow me to post anything for the next two days.

Comment: Gotcha. I didnt know that. Yeah they're sticklers for the rules. Might want to try editing your question, trying out how to make a picture appear in the question instead of linking to outside content. It might provoke a change in the down/up votes. Good luck!